# WxWidgets very silent install parameter

Tags: wxwidgets, silent-installer

I would like to have a very silent install of wxWidgets (using the [3.0.2 install](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.2/wxMSW-3.0.2-Setup.exe/download) for example).

I've tried the usual suspects:

```
/s /S /q /Q /quiet /silent /SILENT /VERYSILENT
```

So far only `/silent` gives a result - An install window without any user interaction.

Its good but is there another option that gives a completely silent result, without the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets installer uses (excellent) Inno Setup and so supports its standard [command line parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline), so `/verysilent` should work.

This being said, what's the point of using the installer non interactively anyhow? This may be necessary with some programs which don't provide any other way of installing them, but with wxWidgets you should just grab the archive (7z one preferably) and uncompress it wherever you want, this is almost all the installer does anyhow.

Comment: verysilent gives the same result as silent. The point of it is to create the most silent install for a [chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/). Your idea of 7unzipping is good, I'll see if it would be better than the actual install.